# Simple web interface with beaglebone black

Tags: embedded-systems

This is actually a very simple question, but I'm lost at the moment.

I was using a beaglebone black for a school project. It controls a bunch of motors and actuators,etc. We wrote everything in C++, and made libraries of functions. When a main program calls them, the functions run just fine.

Recently we have been told to demo our progress so far. The main program is nowhere near done, so we were thinking of some sort of web interface that can execute the complied C++ program on command. We were hoping to get the server hosted on the board, and access it via LAN from other PCs. But I've never done this before and have no idea where to start. Does node.js (with the 'bonescript') going to be of any help? Or is there a simpler way with basic HTML?

I only have a few days to figure it out, so I didn't want to waste time looking at the wrong methods.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you want to display via your web interface? Do you just want to show the output of your program? Do you want to send commands to your program?

Comment: For now, it's even simpler than that. The interface is going to have some buttons which is going to execute specific compiled C++ programs. The output is hardware outputs connected to LEDs.

Comment: To be clear, you don't want any feed back then, correct? Also, do you already have a web server installed (e.g. Apache)?

Comment: No feedback needed. I haven't installed any web server yet.

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8427954/2063546

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience with the BeagleBone Black and only limited experience with Angstrom. With that said I can tell you that you will need a web server installed. Your simplest approach from their would be to use something like Python, Perl, or PHP to exec your process. Not something I would ever recommend for a production environment but it will suffice for what you are trying to do. Alternatively you may consider writing a simple C++ server using TCP/IP and instead have it exec your process. HTH